# Ebay Trading API discountPriceInfo.OriginalPrice doesn't show

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-lms

I want to show the originalPrice over my Price in my ebay auction.

I see that a lot of sellers do it so it is possible.

I add the follow code to my AddItem Request:

```
<DiscountPriceInfo>
    <OriginalRetailPrice currencyID="EUR">100.00</OriginalRetailPrice>
</DiscountPriceInfo>
```

The Api Return **Success** but the Original price isn't show!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about Strike-Through Pricing (STP), correct?

According to the [eBay docs here](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/AddItem.html#Request.Item.DiscountPriceInfo), this is only valid for US, UK, and DE -- and the seller may need special approval by eBay to use STP.

Comment: Yeah I discovered that I can't do it, I need IT(italy)